# necessary and sufficient condition for a linear map defined on a real vector space such that it does not have any real eigen value?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a linear map defined on a real vector space such that it does not have any real eigen value ?

So, if it does not have any real eigen value then dimension must be even. So it is necessary.

Comment: Here's a basically trivial condition: it has no one-dimensional invariant subspace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how your linear map is given to you, but I imagine that you can compute its characteristic polynomial$~\chi\in\Bbb R[X]$, which is for instance the case (in principle, in might be hard by hand) when you have a matrix fro the linear map with respect to some basis. This characteristic polynomial could be any monic real polynomial of degree$~n$, the dimension of your vector space.

Then an obvious necessary and sufficient condition for not having real eigenvalues is that $\chi$ has no real roots. This clearly requires $n$ to be even, but that condition is far from sufficient. The question whether a given even degree real polynomial has any real roots is quite difficult to answer in general (though it is easy for $n\leq2$), but it there is a way to decide this using [Sturm sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).